# Populate text field in django model form based on list box selection

Tags: javascript, django, modelform

I have a django modelform which allows users to create product components.the product id from the table 'product' will be the foreign key in product_component table.The 'product' table is having fields like default_qty and default_price.

When the user creates a product component through modelform they will select the product from the listbox first.The list box will be populated automatically using the foreign key relation.Then i need to populate the default_qty value for the selected product in qty field of current form.

I have seen few solutions using javascript. But not clear about how to implement.Any solutions with or without using js?

Comment: If you want your fields to update themselves without "submitting" the form then JS is the way. Register some change handlers on the elements that trigger the action you want which update other elements. The trick would be to use HTML "data" attributes so that the JS knows what your default etc is

Comment: Makes sense.the trouble for me lies in bringing the data related to foreign key to the template first.